# Using fetch to pass the data to Flask server with ajax causing bad request error

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

This program is about a text summarizer. The input is taken from a text area and then passed to Flask server. I have used ajax fetch to post the data but the code is showing bad request error. How can I resolve the error?

This is the JavaScript part.

```
<body>
    <form method="post">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="60" id="input" type="text"> </textarea>
    <input id="btn-i" type="button" value="Convert" onclick="sendThis()">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="60" id="btn-o" type="text"></textarea>
    </form>


    <script>

    function sendThis() {
        var input = document.getElementById("input").value;

        var  uurl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
        fetch(uurl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: input

            }).then(function (result) {
                console.log(result); 
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                var res = JSON.stringify(result);
                printOutput(res);
            }).catch (function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ', error);
            })
    }

    function printOutput(res) {
        var x = document.getElementById('btn-o');
        x.value = res;
    }
```

And this part is the Flask server. I need to show the output on the same page..

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request

from flask import jsonify
from commons import open_files

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello_world():
   if request.method=='GET':
       return render_template('check.html')

   if request.method=='POST':
       text=request.form['input']
       print(text)
       return jsonify(open_files(text))



if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: `fetch()` is javascript, not jQuery.  I don't see any `jQuery` in the question, so I've removed this tag and added `javascript`.

Comment: Sorry for that..... As i don't know much about it..... I just need it for running my python program which takes a string as an input and returns a string.Taplar